# Backend Locale Options is missing most of the countries?

Tags: magento2, locale

I've a magento 2.2.2, the locale is missing most of the countries in backend
and converted into chinese, where is these options loaded from? How can i fix it?

[image]

Comment: you can copy the default Magento 2.2.2 file into this instalation. So Your issue resolve.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya are you meaning to replace all files in /vendor?

Comment: Yes all the default file from the magento default zip.